# How to show Html list into ListView in Android studio

Tags: android, webview, android-listview

I have a website link and in that website i have a list of items like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTRdT.png)

and i want to show that items in my Android listview like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIiOA.jpg)

How can it be possible? Because i have many pages like that website and i do not want those names copy paste.

Thank you.

Comment: can you take that list in a json form from that link somehow??

Comment: Web developer fully write code in links tag if i parse list in json form than tags will come in that file

Comment: I dont understand anything...

Comment: web developer (website owner) has written the code in html file and in that file he write code in ul>li>a tag to make the list and links and names are in anchor tag so is there any why to bring out that names and links from there.

Comment: I guess you should search for a "HTML Parser" kinda thing...

Comment: thank you @james04 i found jsoup library for that